# How to handle multi-type variables with templates?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming

I was trying to make a function that assigns `y` to `x` regardless whether `x`, `y` are `int` or `std::string`. I wrote this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T>
T& assign(T& x, T& y){

    if ( typeid(x).name() == "Ss" && typeid(y).name() == "Ss" ){
        std::string k = static_cast<std::string>(y);
        x = k;
        return x;
    }

else if ( typeid(x).name() == "i" && typeid(y).name() == "i" ){        
        int k = static_cast<int>(y);
        x = k;
        return x;
}

else{    
        std::cout << "uncorrect assignment" << std::endl;    
    }

}

int main(){

    std::string a = "empty_string";
    std::string b = "Hi there";
    assign(a, b);
    std::cout << a << std::endl;

}
```

But it doesn’t work.
It gives the error:

```
[Error] invalid static_cast from type ‘std::basic_string<char>’ to type
```

at line 14:

```
 int k = static_cast<int>(y);
```

I can’t understand, what is the problem?

I know the objection: I might have just defined function assign as:

```
template <typename T>
T& assign(T& x, T& y){
    x = y;    
}
```

which works. However, I was working on an other more complex function on which I have to (or at least I haven’t found any way other than) use `static_cast`.

So, if you could, please, explain to me what is the mistake in this example, I may try to fix the function I am working on.

Thank you very much,
Simone.

Comment: Why not just use simple overloaded functions? Like `int& assign(int& x, int y)` and `std::string& assign(std::string& x, const std::string& y)`. Also note that because 2nd parameter is input parameter, it should be passed by value or as const reference.

Answer (score 3):

To do what do you want, you need C++17 and `if constexpr`. And the use of something that works compile-time, not of `typeid` that works runtime.

The problem is that with your code, `typeid` permit, **runtime**, to choose the if or the else part of your code, but the compiler must compile both part. So must compile

```
    int k = static_cast<int>(y);
    x = k;
```

when `T` is `std::string`. This give an error.

You need a type-traits (`std::is_same`, by example), that is evaluated compile-time, and a construct that avoid the compilation of the wrong part. This construct is `if constexpr ( <test> )` (where the `<test>` is valuable compile time) but, unfortunately, is available only from C++17.

So, in C++17 you can write

```
template <typename T>
void assign (T & x, T const & y)
 {    
    if constexpr ( std::is_same<T, std::string>::value ) {
       std::string k = static_cast<std::string>(y);
       x = k;
    }
    else if constexpr ( std::is_same<T, int>::value ) {
       int k = static_cast<int>(y);
       x = k;
    }
    else {    
       std::cout << "uncorrect assignment" << std::endl;    
    }
}
```

but, pre C++17, you have to follows different ways.

Comment: Thank you. Can I #include some library to make constexpr and std::is_same work?

Comment: @SiMo - `if constexpr` is part of the language (starting from C++17), so no header is required; for `std::is_same` should be included `<type_traits>`

Answer (score 0):

To handle different types separately inside a function, an option is to define a local `struct` with overloaded [function call operators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/function_call_operator_overloading.htm) to different types:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
T& assign(T& x, const T& y) {
    struct {
        void operator()(std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs) {
            std::cout << "Type is std::string." << std::endl;
            lhs = rhs;
        }
        void operator()(int& lhs, const int& rhs) {
            std::cout << "Type is int." << std::endl;
            lhs = rhs;
        }
    } assign_impl;

    assign_impl(x, y);
    return x;
}

int main() {
    /* Test No. 1 */ {
        std::string dest, src = "Foo";
        std::cout << "Test result: " << assign(dest, src) << std::endl;
    }

    /* Test No. 2 */ {
        int dest, src = 32;
        std::cout << "Test result: " << assign(dest, src) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The code above will work on C++98 and above but its disadvantage is that it will raise compiler errors if you try to use it with unhandled types.